# Create List of classes that extends and implement

Tags: java, class, interface, extends, implements

I have a several classes that define as follow :

```
class A extends Super implements Interface {}
class B extends Super implements Interface {}
```

I want to create list of these classes.
 I try the following:

```
public class C {

    List<Class<?>> classes = Arrays.asList((Class<?>) A.class, B.class); // Works
    List<Class<? extends Super,Interface>> classes2 = Arrays.asList(A.class, B.class); // Compile Error
    List<Class<? extends Super>> classes3 = Arrays.asList(A.class, B.class); // Compile Error

}
```

What is the right way to write it ? Why the first option works when I make casting only to A ?

Comment: What Java version are you using? 1 and 3 work fine for me. 2 doesn't work because `Class` only has one type parameter.

Comment: Java1.7.   1 works for me too but I don't understand why if the casting is done only on A.  For option 3 I got the error in eclipse:Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Class<? extends Super&Interface>> to List<Class<? extends Super>>

Comment: It doesn't need to be. Take it out.

Comment: If I remove the cast before A.class it I got from eclipse:Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Class<? extends Super&Interface>> to List<Class<?>>

Comment: Ah, type inference changes. Removing the cast works on Java 8 only then.

Comment: How can it be written without cast ? Why cast on A.class is enough and I don't need to cast B.class also ?

Answer (score 3):

**line 1** :

it seems to be the way it works, but you can do this :

```
List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(A.class, B.class));
```

**line 2** :

```
java: wrong number of type arguments; required 1
```

it should be `List<Class<? extends Super>>`

**line 3** is ok on my IDE

**line 4 (me)** :

```
List<Class<? extends Super>> classes4 = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Super>>(Arrays.asList(A.class, B.class));
```

-

`Arrays.asList()` only return `AbstractList` and it fails when you use it (`UnsupportedOperationException`), so you must instanciate a implementation.

Thanks